# footable, how to display "sorted" icon after the loading of the page?

Tags: footable

I use the excellent "footable" plugin. I can sort the table by clicking on the header, but how to tell to "footable" : sort this table with this column just after the page is loaded ?

I tried with this keyword : **data-sort-initial**, without success :

```
 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-type="html" data-sort-use="text" data-sort-initial="ascending">Code</th>
                        <th>Libellé</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

My goal is to have this table just after the loading :

[image]

With the "sorted icon" displayed in the header. How to do that ?

My js is simple :

```
$(function () {
    $('.footable').footable();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.

```
<th data-type="html" data-sort-use="text" data-sorted="true" data-direction="ASC">Code</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must add to the column the tag: data-sorted="true"

like this:

```
<th data-type="html" data-sort-use="text" data-sort-initial="ascending" data-sorted="true">Code</th>
```

Comment: This one worked for me in later versions of FooTable. Thanks!